# Java regex; conditions on groups

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex, where the occurence of one group, depends on whether or not another certain group has been found. I think this is easier to illustrate with an example!

I want to allow two patterns, illustrated by these two examples: `JsJh`, `JJ`.
This is not allowed: `JsJs`, `JsJ`, `JQ`.

So if the user types one small letter after the first capital one, the regex expects another small letter after the second capital - but it should not be the same letter as the first one!

I match the first (Js) like this: `([123456789TJQKA]){1}([dsch]?){1}`
The second capital letter is matched by `(\\2)`.

Now, I cannot seem to find a solution for the last small letter. I can get the small letters to match (which is obv. not what I want), but how do I, if its present, exclude the first letter from the last group, by still allowing (and expecting) one of the three remaining small letters?

Comment: Does the duplicate detection have to be done in the regex?  Why not parse card objects first then check them for equality?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... But I think it's "cleaner" to use a regex for the whole thing. Or else, I just start having "else-if's" all over the place :)

Comment: Will the cards always be listed in a predetermined order?  Or could the same hand be represented by `Ac5JsJh` or `JhAcJs5` or whatever?  Also, I notice you're matching both `1` and `A` as card values; don't those both refer to an Ace?

Comment: The 1 was a mistake, it should just be removed from the regex.

The order should not matter! You should be able to write JhJc,A2s+,22+, 88-TT ... in the order you like. But the above regex is just for one token, seperated by comma. So the only situation where the order could matter, is when you apply a ceiling, like 22-55. (And write this as 55-22). But its easily fixed, with a call to Math.max() to find the ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using regular expressions to implement the logic of a card game? Seems pretty crazy... nevertheless it can be done!

```
s.matches("([123456789TJQKA])([dchs])\\1(?!\\2)[dchs]|([123456789TJQKA])\\3")
```

Here is a test to verify that it works correctly (and it also documents my assumptions about the special cases that you haven't covered in your question):

```
public class Test
{
    private static void test(String input, boolean expected)
    {
        boolean result = input.matches("([123456789TJQKA])([dchs])\\1(?!\\2)[dchs]|([123456789TJQKA])\\3");
        if (result != expected)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        test("JJ", true);
        test("JsJd", true);
        test("11", true);
        test("2c2h", true);

        test("Js", false);
        test("JsJs", false);
        test("JsJ", false);
        test("JQ", false);
        test("1d1d", false);
        test("J", false);
        test("", false);
        test("3d3d", false);
        test("JsJdJ", false);
        test("JsJdJh", false);
        test("1A", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The regex is just for parsing hand-ranges. So the user can type in eg. {A2s+, JJ+, 88, AKo, TsTh} as the distribution of hands his opponent might have. 

Your suggestion works wonders! Now I just need to find out what actually happens.

Comment: @Frederik, Just a few minor points: I managed to miss the T - oops! It's added now. Also as Anon. points out you can shorten 123456789 to 1-9.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm still wondering what the **** is going on though. This line: (?!\\2)[dchs]|([123456789TJQKA])\\3, what does it say? I cannot find anything about the '?!'-syntax anywhere. 

Maybe you have a good java regex reference? I cannot find many good resources. Sun's own seems... Not too comprehensive?

Comment: The (?! ... ) is a negative lookahead. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html